# how can I track progress of google cloud skill boost portal courses such as Associate cloud engineer, professional cloud developer etc.?

Tags: python, node.js, google-chrome, google-cloud-platform, cloud

The use case is essentially as follows :

I want to track progress of people who are doing courses such as associate cloud engineer etc. on partner advantage portal for a particular domain ( eg. yourname@domain.com) users. Unfortunately, there does not seem to be any api for this in google apis reference and I am not aware of any other approaches. I have thought of creating a javascript chrome extension to send data to a backend but if google changes ui or updates course content then it will obvious break. Please let me know if anyone has created a poc such as this one or know any service of such sort. Thanks!

we have thought of creating a javascript extension and sync data with external data sync such as datastore or cloud-sql, but it seems error prone as if ui changes or course content changes , it will be very problematic. Please suggest here , thanks !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is not a problem, it is a new thing that we are trying to implement , I am asking if there are any alternatives to the current approach that we are thinking of using. Thanks !